# (iOS 17) Timer created by Siri request always has an alarm sound with it

Tags: ios

...even though my default timer is set to "Stop Playing" when finished.

**Update**: My current solution has been to say "set a sleep timer for x minutes", which has the same effect as "Stop Playing"

Since the update to iOS 17, I see a plus button next to "Start" timer for creating new timers and an option to create presets.

But this is a relegation from iOS 16, as the only use I have for timers is to automatically stop playing media at night, when I need to avoid looking at the screen.